# Formatting Double with 2 decimals and rounded in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, format

Currently, I'm using the following code to format 'value' constant:

```
let formatString = "%.2f";
let value = 2366.34321;

let formattedValue = String(format: formatString, value);
```

The result I'm getting is 2366.34 but I would like it to be a multiple of 0.05. In this case, it should be 2366.35.

What's the best way to approach that?

Comment: BTW, don't need to end your lines with `;` in Swift :-)

Comment: I know but later when I use other languages I don't forget them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let fvalue = round(value/0.05)*0.05
let formattedValue = String(format: formatString, fvalue)
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!

Comment: This is far from the best way to do this. It's much better to use `NumberFormatter` so you get properly localized results.

Comment: Note that In Swift 3 you can use the FloatingPoint round method. `let fvalue = value.divided(by: 0.05).rounded().multiplied(by: 0.05)`. The advantage is that you can specify the rounding method if needed `(.up)` or `(.down)`.